# In Python how can this work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def Sum(*args): 
  Len=0
  n=0
  for(i)in(args):
    if isinstance(args[n],int)==True:
      Len+=args[n]
    elif isinstance(args[n],dict)==True:
      for Key in args[n]:
        Len+=args[n][Key]
    else:
       for(i)in(args[n]):
         Len+=i
    n+=1
  return(Len)
def Bin(*args):
  return Sum(args)
T=7
L={"l":83,"k":33}
M=[22,99,8]
print Sum(T,L,M)
print Bin(T,L,M)
```

This is my code the first function works but the second one doesn't because when it is called in the second functions it tuples it even though it is already a tuple which is why it doesnt work when it is run (incase you think its indentation problem i indent at 2 spaces)

Comment: In the `Bin` function, you should be returning `Sum(*args)` and not `Sum(args)`.

Comment: @Ant i think hes just trying to see why its not working, he looks to be experimenting

Comment: of course.. just stating a fact :-)

Answer (score 2):

You want to `return Sum(*args)` from `Bin`.  The problem is that you're passing a `tuple` to `Sum` which is getting unpacked into a tuple with a single element (which is another tuple) in `Sum`.  e.g. if you `print args` inside `Sum`, you'd see something like:

```
((T,L,M),)
```

instead of:

```
(T,L,M)
```

Comment: yes i had the program printing the args it did come up with ((T,L,M),) im trying to see why it does that when called in a function and thanks ColdFusion i must of forgot to type that in

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to do but here is a minimal one-line fix to actually make the code run (the second inner for-loop now iterates the length of args[n]):

```
def Sum(*args): 
  Len=0
  n=0
  for(i)in(args):
    if isinstance(args[n],int)==True:
      Len+=args[n]
    elif isinstance(args[n],dict)==True:
      for Key in args[n]:
        Len+=args[n][Key]
    else:
       for(i)in range(len(args[n])):
         Len+=i
    n+=1
  return(Len)
def Bin(*args):
  return Sum(args)
T=7
L={"l":83,"k":33}
M=[22,99,8]
print Sum(T,L,M)
print Bin(T,L,M)
```

The output is:

```
126
3
```

I find it nice when posted code has the right amount of empty lines so that others can simply paste the code into a Python >>> prompt. Including Python 3 conformance, and other, stylistic changes, here's what I mean:

```
def Sum(*args): 
    Len = 0
    n = 0
    for i in args:
        if isinstance(args[n], int):
            Len += args[n]
        elif isinstance(args[n], dict):
            for Key in args[n]:
                Len += args[n][Key]
        else:
            for i in range(len(args[n])):
                Len += i
        n += 1
    return Len

def Bin(*args):
    return Sum(args)

T = 7
L = {"l":83,"k":33}
M = [22,99,8]

print(Sum(T,L,M))
print(Bin(T,L,M))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more Pythonic way of adding things up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import numbers

def SumRec(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, numbers.Number):
        return arg
    elif isinstance(arg, dict):
        return sum(SumRec(value) for value in arg.itervalues())
    else:
        return sum(SumRec(thing) for thing in arg)
def Sum(*args):
    return sum(SumRec(arg) for arg in args)

T = 7
L = {"l": 83, "k": 33}
M = [22, 99, 8]
print Sum(T,L,M)
print Sum([T,L,M])
print SumRec([T,L,M])
print 7 + (83 + 33) + (22 + 99 + 8)
```